# Is there a way to convert mm:ss.00 to seconds.00?

Tags: r, time

I've got some performance time data in mm:ss.00 format (i.e. 02:15.45, or 00:34.58).  R is recognizing the variable as a factor, but I'd like to convert each performance time to just seconds (i.e. 02:15.45 to 135.45).  I've searched for an answer but can't seem to find a way to make it work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your "variable" (which I take to mean a column in a dataframe) is really a factor, then you will need to use `as.character()` to get any of the methods below to succeed.

Answer (score 35):

Using lubridate package (part of tidyverse):

```
library(lubridate)
period_to_seconds(hms("12:12:54"))
```

Answer (score 19):

Here's one I've used for a number of years. It's vectorized, too.

```
toSeconds <- function(x){
   if (!is.character(x)) stop("x must be a character string of the form H:M:S")
   if (length(x)<=0)return(x)

   unlist(
      lapply(x,
         function(i){
            i <- as.numeric(strsplit(i,':',fixed=TRUE)[[1]])
            if (length(i) == 3) 
               i[1]*3600 + i[2]*60 + i[3]
            else if (length(i) == 2) 
               i[1]*60 + i[2]
            else if (length(i) == 1) 
               i[1]
         }  
      )  
   )  
}
```

And the reverse (preserves fractional seconds to the number of digits requested:

```
secondsToString <- function(x,digits=2){
   unlist(
      lapply(x,
         function(i){
            # fractional seconds
            fs <- as.integer(round((i - round(i))*(10^digits)))
            fmt <- ''
            if (i >= 3600)
               fmt <- '%H:%M:%S'
            else if (i >= 60)
            fmt <- '%M:%S'
            else
               fmt <- '%OS'

            i <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime("0:0:0","%H:%M:%S")) + i, format=fmt)
            if (fs > 0)
               sub('[0]+$','',paste(i,fs,sep='.'))
            else
               i
         }
      )
   )
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Look into strptime. Specifically

```
t = "02:15.45"
(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(strptime(t, format = "%M:%OS"))) - 
    as.numeric(as.POSIXct(strptime("0", format = "%S"))))
```

This will work, but is possibly a little awkward (doing it this way mostly because of POSIXct's annoying automatic unit conversion...)

Answer (score 7):

```
library(lubridate)
df$variable<- hms(df$variable)
df$variable<- as.numeric(df$variable)
```

make it a one-liner is ok as well. Works like a charm for me.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Best answer for this subject

Answer (score 4):

I am not that much comfortable so i don't know if there is any builtin function available, but i have worked out this code.

```
mmss_to_ss <- function  (string)
{
  mmss <- strsplit (string, ":", T)
  mm <- as.numeric (mmss[[1]][1])
  ss <- as.numeric (mmss[[1]][2])
  return (mm * 60 + ss)
}
```

This will accept a time string in mm:ss format and return second values. The code can be easily modified to convert from hh:mm:ss to seconds also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the Lubridate package. If you use the format "h:m:s" you can convert the variable to a lubridate object with

```
hms("12:12:54")
```

And then convert it to seconds with

```
seconds(hms("12:12:54"))
```

Here is a link to the lubridate article in JSS

http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i03/paper

Comment: This results in "54S" which is not the desired result. The question asks how to convert a duration to seconds, not extract the seconds part of the time object.

Comment: Use `period_to_seconds` in place of `seconds`