# Convert a duration %H:%M:%S to seconds

Tags: r, time, format

```
durations <- "01:01:01" #1 hour 1 min and 1 sec
```

How can I use base R to get the numeric 10-base representation of the seconds (or minutes) this corresponds to (it would be 3661 seconds) ?. Time (and dates) in R always hurts me.
There are plenty of similar SO questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298327/in-r-use-lubridate-to-convert-hms-objects-into-seconds) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019186/r-convert-text-duration-d-h-m-s-into-seconds)) but I still did not really get it right.
One try was:

```
as.numeric(format(strptime('00:01:01', format='%H:%M:%S'), '%S'))
```

Comment: this one has a nice answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835908/is-there-a-way-to-convert-mmss-00-to-seconds-00-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After we convert it to `POSIXlt`, extract the `hour`, `min` and `sec` and do the arithmetic

```
v1 <- strptime(durations, format='%H:%M:%S')
v1$hour * 3600 + v1$min * 60 + v1$sec
#[1] 3661
```

---

Or

```
c(unlist(unclass(v1)[c("hour", "min", "sec")]) %*% c(3600, 60, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
as.numeric(strsplit(durations, ":")[[1]]) %*% c(3600, 60, 1)
```